# trim textfield value and set it for radio button value in the seem screen before submit

Tags: php

i want to get the textfield value and assign it for the radio button value

my code is working but not from the first time 
after the first submit it will work perfectly

how do i make it work from the first page load

here is my code

```
 <input type="text" name="optionAtxt" value="<?php echo @$_POST['optionAtxt'] ?>" />​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ <input type="radio"  name="option" required value="<?php echo @$_POST['optionAtxt'] ?>">
 <input type="text" name="optionBtxt" value="<?php echo @$_POST['optionBtxt'] ?>" />​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ <input type="radio"  name="option" value="<?php echo @$_POST['optionBtxt'] ?>"> 
 <input type="text" name="optionCtxt" value="<?php echo @$_POST['optionCtxt'] ?>"/>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ <input type="radio"  name="option" value="<?php echo @$_POST['optionCtxt'] ?>">


<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add" />
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1" />

<?php

if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {

$selected = trim($_POST['option']);

echo $selected;

}?>
```

Comment: Eeee.... How do you want to set POST value when POST was not sent? There is no logic in this move.

Comment: i know that but i want to do it in any way :(  is it possible ? even with jQuery @nospor